# Build Docker image but don't save?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

We're using Docker to release our server to our different environments, but we're also using Docker to build our server in a multi-stage docker build. When we're just building a PR, there is no point to have docker create an image and clutter our build server with non-pushed docker images.

Is there a way to have Docker build an image, and not save it to disk, or immediately delete it afterwards?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you could use the `--output` option and send the image to /dev/null

```
 docker build --output type=tar,dest=/dev/null .
```

Comment: Link to the reference for the curious ones: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs

Comment: this is great idea! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it would be possible to create containers without saving the images on the disk. But, it is possible to delete "all images without at least one container associated to them" using [prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) command:

```
docker image prune --all
```

Otherwise, you have to get the ID of the newly created image (e.g. using `docker-compose images -q`) and then delete them using `docker rmi <image_id>`.